# Angle Label Issues

Tags: tkz-euclide

I am trying to label the angles of a triangle. I can't figure out why my code is kicking the name to the outside. My apologies for any formatting issues; this is my first post here.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}  
\usetkzobj{all}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt}]  
\path  
  (80:5) node [dot,label=above left:$A$]{} coordinate (A)  
  (20:9) node[dot, label=right:$B$]{} coordinate (B)  
  (0:0) node[dot,label=below left:$C$]{} coordinate(C);  

\path coordinate (Q)at($(C)!(A)!(B)$) node at (Q)[]{} ;  

 \draw[-]  (A)--(C);  
 \draw[-] (C)--(B);  
 \draw[-] (A)--(B);  
 \draw[purple!70!black] (A)--(Q);  

\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,Q,C);  

\draw[|<->|] ($(P)!-7mm!90:(B)$)--node[fill=white,sloped] {$x$} ($(B)!-7mm!-90:(P)$);  
\draw[|<->|] ($(Q)!-4.9mm!90:(A)$)--node[fill=white] {$10$} ($(A)!-3mm!-90:(Q)$);  

\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.75cm,color=black,label=$\alpha$](B,C,A);  
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=black,label=$\beta$](A,B,Q);  
\tkzMarkRightAngle(B,A,C);  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[Here is a picture of the triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRDv5.png)

Comment: Can you please format it instead of just posting the code? thanks. Also, try posting it in the LaTeX website of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Have you tried this ‘\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,color=black,label=$\beta$](Q,B,A); ‘